# ORA-01036 illegal variable name/number - Select Where Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, gridview

I'm trying to execute a simple `select .... where` statement on an Oracle DB 11g.

When the user hits the Edit button, it sends the record fields back from the gridview into the DAL. I want to retrieve the existing record from DB to compare with the edited record from gridview to see what edits the user has made. I keep getting the above error using this code. I have verified that the problem is with the WHERE statment and that `ProductCode` has a value on execution so not sure why it's mad.

```
public virtual void EditProduct(ProductRecord productRecord)
        {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
        OracleTransaction transaction = null;
        if (conn != null)
            {
            try
                {
                conn.Open();
                transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

                string sql = "SELECT DIRECTION, PRODUCTCODE, PRODUCTDESC, ISACTIVE 
                from PRODUCT PRD where PRD.PRODUCTCODE = :PRM_ProductCode";

                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);

                OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter("PRM_ProductCode",OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param.Value = productRecord.ProductCode;
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new OracleParameter("PRM_ProductCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param.Value = productRecord.ProductCode;
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new OracleParameter("PRM_DIRECTION", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param.Value = productRecord.Direction;
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new OracleParameter("PRM_IsActive", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param.Value = productRecord.Active;
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                param = new OracleParameter("PRM_ProductDesc", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                param.Value = productRecord.ProductDesc;
                command.Parameters.Add(param);

                OracleDataReader rs = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (rs.Read())
                {
                  ..code
                }
                rs.Close();
                command.Dispose();

                //Update existing product record with new product record
                sql = "UPDATE PRODUCT SET DIRECTION = :PRM_DIRECTION, ISACTIVE = :PRM_IsActive, PRODUCTDESC = :PRM_ProductDesc WHERE PRODUCTCODE = :PRM_ProductCode";
                command = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);                    

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Dispose();
                transaction.Commit();
                }
             catch (Exception ex)
                {
                transaction.Rollback();
                }
             finally
                {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

**note** `ProductCode` is not a primary key. Unfortunately the PK is not currently evaluated when passing the record from the gridview. However, `ProductCode` is a unique field. Any help would be appreciated.

`productRecord` is being passed in from the presentation layer.

Comment: try `PRODUCTCODE` instead of `PRD.PRODUCTCODE` in *where*.

Comment: didn't work unfortunately. I get the same error.

Comment: Have you added a parameter named `PRM_ProductCode` to your command? Please show some more code.

Comment: Yes. I'm also using an OracleTransaction and it fails at command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: How the binding of the parameter is done?

Comment: param = new OracleParameter("PRM_ProductCode", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    param.Value = productRecord.ProductCode;
                    command.Parameters.Add(param);

Comment: productRecord is being passed in from the presentation layer.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include clarifications or more information. Use the Comments section for just comments (i.e. things which can be deleted without damaging the question. Code samples are especially hard to read as comments.

Comment: Why do you execute a query with `executeNonQuery()`?

Comment: Should that not be used? Excuse me, I'm kind of new to .NET.

Comment: You are trying to execute a _query_. A nonquery is an update or a function. So simply use `command.ExecuteReader();` This has little to do with .NET, by the way, but more with understanding how to use a database :)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful @oerkelens. Will change appropriately.

Comment: I've added more information about the structure of the method but again..the problem is in the `where` clause. When I remove it, it continues to run instead of going into my `catch` block. I have also removed `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` but still getting the same error @oerkelens.

Comment: The problem was that I was binding the `DIRECTION` , `IsActive`, and `ProductDesc` variables under the `SELECT` statement along with `ProductCode` where they weren't being used and not under the `UPDATE` statement where they were being used. I thought you could bind them all in one place in the and then use them as needed throughout the method. Apparently you should only bind the variables used in each sql statement no more no less. If one is used again i.e. `ProductCode` then rebind with that statement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute a *query*, which you cannot do with `ExecuteNonQuery` (the name is a bit of a giveaway...)

Try instead `ExecuteReader`, as explained by [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/OracleCommandClass.htm#ODPNT458):

```
// Execute command, create OracleDataReader object
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    // process your result(s)
}
```

Comment: Although this was helpful, it didn't clear up my initial error. Thanks for your time.